# User information retrieval based download in Joomla

Tags: joomla

i am hosting a site in Joomla and we want to allow document downloads. however, we want the downloads only after user submits at least their email.

i searched and found that it could be possible to do this by means of user registration but is there a simpler way by means of a plugin that allows simple user email submission followed by download over full registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *DocMan*, which is a Joomla document management extension. The only issue is that this is a commercial, and it costs $99 for one website. But it is a solid extension.

Don't waste your time writing code to do what you want to do when an extension may do.